# Futures : Taghelpers --> Razor Components

Tags: asp.net-core-tag-helpers, razor-components

I'm wondering if anybody has any views or knowledge on where the future of TagHelpers & Razor Components lay. My question is only with regard to initial rendering. Not using C# code on the client-side.

I love the razor component model of working in the sense that the basic component is laid out in markup, then there is code behind.

This being compared to TagHelpers generating the markup.

Take this TagHelper label component I use for example...

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace gMIS.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("glabel", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
    public class glabelTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        #region Attributes

        [HtmlAttributeName("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeName("class")]
        public string cls { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeName("xy")]
        public string xy { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeName("style")]
        public string style { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeName("value")]
        public string value { get; set; }

        #endregion Attributes

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            //START with the container DIV
            output.TagName = "div";
            output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
            if (id != null) output.Attributes.Add("id", id);
            if ((xy != null) && (xy != null)) output.Attributes.Add("class", "xy" + xy);
            if (style != null) output.Attributes.Add("style", "display:inline-block; font-weight:bold;" + style); //*** Any subsequent WIDTH passed in with supercede the default provided here!
            else output.Attributes.Add("style", "display:inline-block; font-weight:bold;");
            if (cls != null) output.Attributes.Add("class", cls);

            //Insert data value
            if (value != null) output.Content.AppendHtml(value);
        }
    }
}
```

I would love it if this could be coded something like...

```
<div id="{inject id}" class="{inject class}" style="{inject style}">{inject text}</div>
```

...rather than using C# to create the basic markup.

```
output.TagName = "div";
output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
```

Then the code behind interacts (only server-side) to finish the configuration of the basic component markup. That way, you can see the basic markup rather than the more difficult to read and visualize C# construction of the markup.

With a basic label this seems like not much of a gain, but with more complex components, being able to visualize the markup would be a real boon.

```
    <div class="{inject class}" id="{inject id}" style="{inject style}">
        <input name="{inject name}" id="{inject id}" style="{inject style}" type="text" value="-4" data-val-required="&amp;nbsp;Req!" data-val="true">
        <input id="{inject id}" style="{inject style}" type="text" placeholder="Start typing here to search..." autocomplete="off">
        <select id="{inject id}" style="{inject style}" size="1">
        </select>

        <script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function () {       $('#ext_IT_Task_Reported_By_ID').glookupInit('/TagHelpers/InternalContactLookup');   });</script>

        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="{inject id}"></span>
    </div>
```

Does anybody know where Taghelpers is heading the longer term? Towards the Razor Component way of construction perhaps. Apologies if my post isn't clear enough. I have thought hard about how to communicate my question. I do hope it's not confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're asking here, but I think you're not understanding how tag helpers work. You don't have to add each attribute manually to the output and you certainly don't need backing properties if you don't actually need the value for the purposes of the tag helper. Razor leaves any additional attributes unmolested.

```
[HtmlTargetElement("glabel")]
public class glabelTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "div";
        output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;

        var style = "display:inline-block; font-weight:bold";
        if (output.Attributes.TryGetAttribute("style", out var attr))
        {
            style += $";{attr.Value}";
        }
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("style", style);
    }
}
```

Based on your code, the only thing you're modifying is the `style` attribute, so everything else, including the content, can and will just come over as-is. Then, for the style, you just need to see if the attribute already exists, and if so, append that to your custom style. With just the code above:

```
<glabel id="foo" class="foo" style="width:100px">
    <!-- child content here -->
</glabel>
```

Will result in:

```
<div id="foo" class="foo" style="display:inline-block;font-weight:bold;width:100px">
    <!-- child content here -->
</div>
```

The child elements would need to be their own tag helpers if you need to do special stuff there. A tag helper only operates on the immediate tag itself, not an entire block of HTML. You can get the child content and manually modify it, but you'd be doing so as just a string, having to use stuff like regex. Suffice it to say, that would be less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Pratt (How do I reference another user properly?)

Unfortunately, you do misunderstand the question. I'm not having problems creating TagHelpers or understanding how they work. We have some 20-25 TagHelpers that we have developed, ranging from Dynamic lookups to our own fairly extensive and powerful grid. Example of grid usage below...

```
<ggrid id="grdTaskSearchResults"
       url="Task_Search?handler=results&userguid=@Model.UserGUID&manager=@Model.Manager"
       sortby="@Model.Opt_SortCol"
       sortdir="@Model.Opt_SortDir"
       pagesize="100"
       style="height:100%; width:100%;">
    <cols>
        <coltemplate style="white-space:nowrap;">
            <a onclick="gNewWindowAndTitle('View IT Call Log', null, null, 'Task_Summary?userguid=@Model.UserGUID&taskId={Task_ID}')" title="View IT Call Log"><img class="smallIcon" src="/Icons/Magnify.gif" /></a>
            <gpdialog btnexit="Cancel" btnsubmitandclose="Save" title="Edit Call Log" url="Task_CRUD?userguid=@Model.UserGUID&manager=@Model.Manager&crud=u&taskId={Task_ID}" callback="ggridReload('grdTaskSearchResults')" linkicon="/Icons/Edit.gif" hideif="('@Model.Manager' !== 'true')" suppresstitle="true" />
            <gpdialog btnexit="Cancel" btnsubmitandclose="Save" title="Add Note to Call Log" url="Task_Note_CRUD?userguid=@Model.UserGUID&taskId={Task_ID}" callback="ggridReload('grdTaskSearchResults')" linkicon="/Icons/NewAddition.gif" suppresstitle="true" />
            <img class='smallIcon' src="/Icons/Exclamation.gif" alt='Not Responded yet!' hideif="{Responded}===true" />
        </coltemplate>
        <col heading="ID" fld="Task_ID" />
        <col heading="Type" fld="Task_Type" style="white-space:nowrap;" />
        <col heading="Status" fld="Task_Status" />
        <coltemplate heading="Reported By">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://gmis.info/entity/entity.asp?ec=1&code={Reported_By_ID}">{Reported_By_Name}</a>
        </coltemplate>
        <col heading="Date Entered" fld="Date_Entered" style="white-space:nowrap;" format="ddMMMyy" />
        <col heading="NAB" fld="NAB_Initials" style="white-space:nowrap;" />
        <coltemplate heading="Severity">
            <span hideif="{Task_Status_ID}===3" style="color:{Severity_Color}; font-family:Webdings; font-size:10pt;">n</span><span hideif="{Task_Status_ID} == 3">&nbsp;&nbsp;{Task_Severity}</span>
        </coltemplate>
        <col heading="Description" fld="Description" />
    </cols>
    <footer>
        <gpdialog btnexit="Cancel" btnsubmitandclose="Save" title="Add New Call Log" url="Task_CRUD?userguid=@Model.UserGUID&manager=@Model.Manager&crud=c" callback="ggridReload('grdTaskSearchResults')" linkicon="/Icons/NewAddition.gif" />
    </footer>
</ggrid>
```

That said, there's a couple of things in your code sample that I would like to look at in my own code. A potential improvement for us I think I can envisage in there. So in that regard, I thank you very much for your input.

No, my question is purely about the next step in the TagHelper story.

- HtmlHelpers were written in c# and called in c#.
- Taghelpers are written in c# and called in html markup.
- Razor Components are written in html markup with some c# code inline/behind. However best implemented in Blazor using html markup. When called from within Razor pages, the call is made in c# code a little like HtmlHelpers were (a backward step for me).

What I would like to see somewhere in this story for the future, is a scenario wherby TagHelpers are written in html markup, with some c# code inline/behind, just like Razor components are now. And in use, the Taghelper called in markup as they are currently. I'm not suggesting that TagHelpers start to use c# on the client side. This is purely about how TagHelpers in their current guise and functionality... are written.

In essence, I am asking if anybody knows what the future holds for in terms of the next step for TagHelpers? Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think a couple of years on, and I know the answer I was looking for. Moving forward at some point, blazor components are the next thing in line. I'm now considering converting all my taghelpers to blazor components in the future. At the moment, the only thing stopping me is the fact that you have to use some very verbose c# code within a razor page to use a blazor conponent. I'm hanging fire till they inevitably I feel, make it so you can use Html markup to consume blazor components within razor pages.